# Advertising local HTTP services via Avahi/Zeroconf on Debian

Tags: debian, avahi

I have a Debian server on local network for home media center/NAS purposes. It is running multiple services such as Plex, or Ajenti, which I can access like so:

```
http://debian.local:32400/web for Plex
https://debian.local:8000/ for Ajenti
```

However I would like to access these services like so:

```
http://plex.local for Plex
https://ajenti.local for Ajenti
```

Is this possible to configure via avahi alone, or what other simple solution would you suggest?

Comment: Well, `http://host/` defaults to port 80 (and similarly `https://` is 443). So just adding *names* isn't going to help. In other words, I fear a solution isn't going to be simple...

Comment: I could install a reverse proxy on the server, but I'm not sure about the DNS (I want to avoid having to install and configure dns for the whole network..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way to do the thing you're directly asking is to add those hosts as aliases to /etc/avahi/hosts (which reads like /etc/hosts) so that those work and are advertised over zeroconf/avahi . The second thing would be to install a reverse proxy (using Apache or Nginx or something) to forward requests for those hosts to the right service.

No idea how well plex will work behind a reverse proxy, though.